# prove that there exists no integer in $\pm\frac1k \pm \frac1{k+1}\pm\frac1{k+2}...\pm\frac1{k+n} $

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Prove that there exists no integer among the $2^{n+1}$ numbers

$$\pm\frac1k \pm \frac1{k+1}\pm\frac1{k+2}...\pm\frac1{k+n} $$

That is,

$$\mathbb{Z} \cap \left\lbrace \frac{\delta_0}{k} + \frac{\delta_1}{k + 1} + \ldots + \frac{\delta_n}{k+n} : \delta_0, \ldots, \delta_n \in \lbrace -1, 1 \rbrace \right\rbrace = \emptyset$$

This is a discrete maths homework question with another part preceding it which wants us to prove that "in any block of consecutive positive integers there is a unique integer divisible by
a higher power of $2$ than any of the others". This I could prove (by negation) so **you can use this statement to answer the question**.

Any suggestions of approaches to the problem are welcome.

Comment: Hi krishna, I've edited your question with an explanation that I think is clearer. Please feel free to roll it back if you disagree, or my interpretation is incorrect.

Comment: @Suzet The numbers aren't listed; you're supposed to perform every possible combination of addition and subtraction between these $n + 1$ fractions, to obtain (at most) $2^{n+1}$ possibilities (see the set equality below).

Comment: I think there are $2^{n+1}$ elements as we can choose each ${\delta}_i$ to be either $-1$ or $1$ and there are $n+1$ choices for $i$. If there are only $2(n+1)$ "distinct" ones can you explain why?

Comment: Also, beware of the trivial solution: $k = 1$ and $n = 0$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Aaah, I understand now ! I read it wrong. Sorry for my useless comment, I shall delete it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $m$ be the exponent of this
maximum power of 2,
so $2^m$ divides exactly one denominator.

Consider the lcm of the denominators $d$.
$2^m|d$. 
When all the fractions are written in the form
$c/d$, the one whose denominator
is divisible by $2^m$ will have
an odd numerator
and all the others will have
an even numerator.
Therefore their sum will be odd,
so the resulting fraction
will have an odd numerator
and even denominator
and so can not
be an integer.

Comment: You need to first prove that the term with the maximum power is unique, this is the hard part of the question.

Comment: I have mentioned in the question that you can assume first part done as I proved it already.

Comment: @krishna: I missed that.

Comment: It's actually pretty easy. If 2 terms are divisible by $2^m$, between them must be a term divisible by$2^{m+1}$ which contradicts $m$ being the maximum exponent.

Comment: @marty, "There must be" would also have an explanation?? How would you go about proving it?

Comment: If there are two terms exactly divisible by $2^m$, they must be $a2^m$ and $b2^m$ with $a$ and $b$ odd and $a<b$. Between them is $(a+1)2^m$. Since $a$ is odd, $a+1$ is even, so $(a+1)2^m$ is divisible by$2^{m+1}$ which contradicts $m$ being the maximum exponent.

Answer (score 3):

Factor all the $n+1$ integers $k,k+1,\cdots,k+n$ and extract the factor $2$ all together. We have $$i=2^{\lambda_i}p_i,$$ where $i=k,k+1,\cdots,k+n.$

Apparently, $\lambda_i \geq 0$ and $2 \nmid p_i.$ Denote $\lambda=\max\{\lambda_i\}.$ Then $\lambda>0$ when $n\geq 1.$ Morover, we may prove there exists only one $i$ such that $i=2^\lambda p_i$. Otherwise, if $i=2^\lambda p_i$ and $j=2^\lambda p_j$ but $i \neq j$, then there exists another even integer between $p_i $ and $p_j$(since $p_i$ and $p_i$ are two different odd integers), which implies there exists a $l$ between $i$ and $j$ such that $l=2^{\lambda+1}p_l.$ This contradicts the assumption that $\lambda$ is the largest.

Now, assume $m=2^\lambda p_m.$ Multiply $$\pm\frac{1}{k}\pm \frac{1}{k+1}\pm \cdots \pm \frac{1}{k+n}$$

by $X=2^{\lambda-1}p_{k}p_{k+1}\cdots p_{k+n}$. Apparently, $M$ could be divided by almost every  denominator except for $m$. Thus, we may write $$\left(\pm\frac{1}{k}\pm \frac{1}{k+1}\pm \cdots \pm \frac{1}{k+n}\right)X=Y\pm\frac{p_kp_{k+1}\cdots p_{k+n}}{2 p_m},\tag1$$
where $Y$ is an integer. Notice that $p_k,p_{k+1},\cdots,p_{k+n}$ are all odd integers. Hence, the product of them except for $p_m$ could not be divided by $2$. Therefore, the right-hand side of $(1)$ is not an integer, from which we may complete the proof.